# Como cambiar currentTime de un elemento HTML audio creado?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

He visto distintos ejemplos de

```
elemento.currentTime
```

Pero no he visto ninguno con un elemento creado desde javascript al que se le aplique y el siguiente codigo no funciona.

```
var time;
var audioe = document.createElement("audio");
audioe.src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/Tiger Growling-SoundBible.com-258880045.mp3";
audioe.onloadeddata = function() {
audioe.currentTime = 2;
audioe.play();
};
```

Alguien ve el problema :/ ?

Comment: Hola Ismael, que significa que no funciona? Hay algún mensaje de error?

Comment: Hola Carlos, el problema es que independientemente de el valor que le de, siempre se reinicia la reproducción como si le dijera currentTime=0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hay problema ninguno, incluso en tu ejemplo, `currentTime` está funcionando como debe.

Lo que falla en el código de arriba: usas un audio que dura 2.063 segundos, entonces cuando haces que empiece en el segundo 2.0, realmente ya no queda nada que escuchar. Si en lugar de ir al sgundo 2, vas al 1.1, verás (o escucharás) como `currentTime` funciona correctamente:

```js
var time;
var audioe = document.createElement("audio");
audioe.src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/Tiger Growling-SoundBible.com-258880045.mp3";
audioe.onloadeddata = function() {
  audioe.play();
  audioe.currentTime = 1.1;
};
audioe.onended = function(e) {
  console.log("El audio dura: " + audioe.currentTime);
};
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(audioe);
```